# Why did aarti mahajan went to take help from CBI if she was the culprit?

Tags: plot-explanation, rahasya

In the movie [Rahasya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahasya) why did aarti mahajan went to take help from CBI when she knew she committed the murder?

Aarti mahajan paid the cop bribe for butchering the investigation and putting his husband behind bars. But later when she was successful with her cunning plan she went to take help from women's association which redirected the case to CBI, leading to her arrest. Why would she do that?

Comment: Maybe because it would have been suspicious if she hadn't? Can you tell us a bit more about the situation and what prompted this question?